# jQuery Mobile does not look very good in Android's 2.3.4 Browser

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I have an Android 4.0 device and a Smartphone with Android 2.3.4. I just started to study jQuery mobile and I noticed that the jQuery mobile's visual doesn't look good in android 2.3.4, seems the buttons are "pixelized" and the transitions don't work. Does somebody know how to fix this? Is that a problem with the jQuery mobile's version?

I'm using jQuery mobile 1.0.1 and jQuery 1.6.4 as recomended in the oficial site.

Thanks.

Comment: Transitions are a known problem of jquerymobile with Android.

Comment: I would recommend sencha touch instead of jquery for mobile development. http://www.sencha.com/products/touch

Comment: Hi everyone! Well, sadly I'm starting to think that the facility to make multiplatform apps using jQuery mobile or sencha touch has a big price to be paid. We lose performance, we lose visual confort, we have bugs that sometimes can't be fixed by ourselves. So, I think that develop "pure" native apps is the best solution.

Comment: Well, I disagree with you. 
Performance is not a big deal as we already have quad core devices with 1 GB of ram.
The speed in development and not having to write everything 3 or 4 times in different languages/apis paid the price for some overhead. Specially if you are targeting enterprise software.

Comment: In part I agree with you. But the problem here isn't the hardware, is the version of the Android in the device (2.3.4). I don't think that is confortable for the user to download a compatible browser to use the app. My smartphone is a Sony Xperia Mini Pro SK17 and his hardware is very good, don't lag any native app. So, my plains are: Make a jQuery Mobile app/ Sencha touch app > Use PhoneGap to make a native app > give it to the users. PhoneGap "encapsulates" the web app using the default browser's core, technically the bugs and low performance will still be there right?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "download a compatible browser to use the app". I use it for enterprise development and never had to make the user download anything except the application itself.
Neither this one: "technically the bugs and low performance will still be there right". Bugs can appear in native or js code, is not about the language.
If your are going to develop games or software for general purpose, could be a good idea to go native, but in general sencha performs really well.

Comment: When I say "download a compatible browser to use the app", I mean: When the browser (by the way, the one that comes with android gb) shows a bug, sometimes the correction is to download a compatible browser to correct it. Look, transitions don't work very well in Android's 2.3 browser, but works in Firefox Mobile. I **totally agree** with you that if we are developing an enterprise app, we don't need to have transitions just to make the webapp / PhoneGap app looks great. But when I make one app to "standard users" the visual impact can't be discarded. That's what I mean.

Comment: Well @Oscar, I really have to say that the application inside PhoneGap looks better than in browser. I just tested now. The transitions are better too, but the buttons not with smooth strikes :/

Comment: and when I change the orientation of the phone the app crashes.